# How to use WebDriverWait with a str variable By.XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, variables, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm having trouble finding how to implement the implicit wait when I have a string variable in the xpath.

I'm currently using a 10 second explicit wait before getting to this snippet and it works good, but I don't want to wait 10 seconds if I don't have to (it's usually around 6 seconds to load)

```
try:
    link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@data-recordindex = '"+str(i)+"']//img[contains(@class,'x-tree-expander')]")
    datarow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@data-recordindex = '"+str(i)+"']")
    print("Level: " +str(level)+ ": " +datarow.text)
    link.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    not_a_point = False
```

I've tried this and it's not waiting, just taking the next link and not the one I'm waiting on to appear.   I'm assuming I can't just put the same thing in By.XPATH as I put in `find_element_by_xpath()`.

```
try:
    link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@data-recordindex = '"+str(i)+"']//img[contains(@class,'x-tree-expander')]")))
    datarow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@data-recordindex = '"+str(i)+"']")
    print("Level: " +str(level)+ ": " +datarow.text)
    link.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    not_a_point = False
```

Comment: the XPATH tree traversal is a little non-intuitive... your second part //img[contains(@class,'x-tree-expander') will search the entire DOM not children of the first part of the path... I'd suggest using a more specific XPATH if you can.  Style classes generally aren't specific enough.

Comment: What is the error, you are getting? str(i) - does the ' i ' start with 0 or 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- [ImplicitWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706) isn't that effective when dealing with dynamic elements/websites and you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518467/how-to-properly-configure-implicit-explicit-waits-and-pageloadtimeout-through/50524225#50524225).
- **10** seconds or **6** seconds the timespan for [Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168663/skip-waiting-for-a-website-timer-selenium-python/50168869#50168869) must be implemented as per the *Test Design Docs*.
- As I answered to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049678/what-is-the-difference-here-that-prevents-this-from-working/64049742#64049742) to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *variable*:

    ```
    link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@data-recordindex = '" + str(i) + "']//img[contains(@class,'x-tree-expander')]")))
    ```
  - Using `%s`:

    ```
    link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@data-recordindex = '%s']//img[contains(@class,'x-tree-expander')]"% str(i))))
    ```
  - Using `{}`:

    ```
    link = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@data-recordindex = '{}']//img[contains(@class,'x-tree-expander')]".format(str(i)))))
    ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions on how to deal with variables within [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) in:

- [Variable in xpath in Python Selenium when calling Class and Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63952477/variable-in-xpath-in-python-selenium-when-calling-class-and-function/63952605#63952605)
- [Auto click a button in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59311956/auto-click-a-button-in-a-web-page/59312802#59312802)
- [Using a variable in xpath in Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874539/using-a-variable-in-xpath-in-python-selenium/62204354#62204354)
- [Web scraping with selenium and python - xpath with contains text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62553465/web-scraping-with-selenium-and-python-xpath-with-contains-text/62554616#62554616)